# How to determine epoch time range from today to past date, then determine equal amount of past time?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs, epoch

[image]

- So I know what today is: **Thu 14 Jul =** `1468523547`
- And I have an `alert` value for 1 week ago: **Thu 07 Jul** = `1467918688`
- Now I need my `start_epoch` (2weeks ago) that would equal the time between **today** and my `alert`. So that I can center my graph.

In my case above, I need to determine 1 week ago from the `alert`.

*Timespans could be a week and a half ago, 6 days etc etc*

Is there an easy way to accomplish this using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: You can define a constant - `day_in_sec = 86400` and calculate your start time using that.

Comment: I think you are talking about the `today` which is the `end_epoch` correct? I can get that now, what I'm trying to determine is a past date, which would be the `start_epoch` in highchart

Comment: `start_epoch = end_epoch - (day_in_sec * 7)`. Do you want it to be at a specific time of the day?

Comment: Ok this is a good start, but the time difference from my `alert` to `end` could be anything... 1.5 weeks, 3 months, 2 days etc... I guess first how would I calculate that difference?

Comment: So basically, what is the most basic unit you are sure of? Can your start date be 1.729564 weeks earlier or something or simply like 1 month 10 days 3 hours 42 seconds earlier or something? What is a sample input for this?

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj—your example of "something simple" isn't. Months are not all of equal length, nor are all days where daylight saving is observed. Should 31 May + 1 month be 30 June or 1 July? What is the result of 31 December - 1 month? Business rules are required to determine outcomes where purely mathematic solutions are illogical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to start exactly one week before `alert`, but keep `alert` exactly in the middle between `start` and `end` (today), then it will be just the same time difference as between alert and end.

```
difference = end - alert
```

then subtract `difference` from `alert` to get `start`.

```
start = alert - difference
```

That's it. `alert` will be exactly in the middle of `start` and `end`.